# A question in Forster

Tags: riemann-surfaces, complex-geometry

Here is a question which has been bothering me for a week. It comes from Otto Forster's lectures on Riemann surfaces. The question comes from Exercise 10.1(c):

Let $X$ be a riemann surface and $\omega$ a holomorphic 1-form on $X$. If $\varphi$ is a local primitive of $\omega$ in a neighbourhood of a point $a\in X$. Let $(Y,p,f,b)$ be a maximal analytic continuation of $\varphi$. Show that

(c) The covering $p:Y\rightarrow X$ is Galois and Deck(Y/X) is abelian.

I can't show that Deck(Y/X) is abelian. In fact, what I have tried is as follows: I let $t:\tilde{X}\rightarrow X$ be the universal covering of $X$, and $\tilde{F}$ the primitive of $t^{*}\omega$. Then we have a group homomorphism

$\tau:\mbox{Aut}(\tilde{X}\rightarrow X)\rightarrow(\mathbb{C},+)$,

given by

$\sigma\mapsto F-\sigma F=F-F\circ\sigma^{-1}:=a_{\sigma}$.

I am done if the kernel of this map is $\mbox{Aut}(\tilde{X}\rightarrow Y)$, for then

$\mbox{Aut}(Y\rightarrow X)=\frac{\mbox{Aut}(\tilde{X}\rightarrow X)}{\mbox{Aut}(\tilde{X}\rightarrow Y)}=\frac{\mbox{Aut}(\tilde{X}\rightarrow X)}{\mbox{ker}\tau}$

and hence is abelian.

I have managed to show that $\mbox{Aut}(\tilde{X}\rightarrow Y)\subseteq\ker\lambda$, but the obstruction lies in the reverse inclusion.

Perhaps someone can me some hint on how to proceed, or to give a completely new idea to this question.

Thanks!

Opps, in fact the $Aut(A\rightarrow B)$ is actually $\mbox{Deck}(A/B)$ because I am using the French notation for deck transformation.

Answer (score 3):

Since any two local primitives of $\omega$ differ by a constant, analytic continuation along closed curves defines a homomorphism $\psi\colon\pi_1(X) \to (\mathbb{C},+)$.  Let $K$ be the kernel of this homomorphism.  Then $Y$ is the cover of $X$ corresponding to $K$, and $\mathrm{Deck}(Y/X)$ is isomorphic to the quotient $\pi_1(X)/K$.  This quotient is isomorphic to the image of $\psi$, which is abelian since it's a subgroup of $(\mathbb{C},+)$.

Comment: That was what I was trying to say in the question. The problem is to show that Deck(Y/X) is isomorphic to the quotient of $\pi_{1}(X)/K$ (or $Y$ is a cover of $X$ corresponding to $K$). How do I show this?

Comment: In general, if $Y$ is a Galois cover of $X$ corresponding to a normal subgroup $N$ of $\pi_1(X)$, then the Deck transformation group $\mathrm{Deck}(Y/X)$ is naturally isomorphic to $\pi_1(X) / N$.  See Hatcher's _Algebraic Topology_, Proposition 1.39.

Comment: Yes, but the problem I am having is to show that the N in question is the kernel of the homomorphism. How do I show this?

Comment: Doesn't that follow directly from the fact that $Y$ is obtained via a "maximal analytic continuation"?  I mean, if you define $N$ to be the kernel of the homomorphism, then the corresponding cover certainly has a well-defined primitive for $\omega$ on it.  Moreover, $N$ is the minimal subgroup of $\pi_1(X)$ for which this statement holds, so the cover corresponding to $N$ must indeed be $Y$.

Comment: I think i get what you mean. Do you mean that if we let $Y=\tilde{X}/H$ for some subgroup $H$, by maximal analytic continuation we have $\tilde{X}/N$ covers $Y$, and hence $N\subseteq H$?

Comment: That sounds about right.

Comment: Argh! I tried that idea but I can't show that the existing morphism to $Y$ is a covering map. Can you explain why $N$ is the minimal subgroup for which the primitive exists?

Comment: Well, a primitive will exist on a cover if and only if the subgroup of $\pi_1(X)$ corresponding to the cover is contained in the kernel of $\psi$.

Comment: Looking back on everything you've written, I think part of the trouble may be that you using the universal cover as a reference point for understanding the Galois correspondence between subgroups of $\pi_1(X)$ and covers of $X$.  It is much simpler to deal with the Galois correspondence directly, i.e. each subgroup $H\leq \pi_1(X)$ corresponds to a cover of $X$, with the property that a loop in $X$ lifts to a loop in the cover if and only if the loop corresponds to an element of $H$.

Comment: In this case, a subgroup $H$ corresponds to a cover on which the primitive is well-defined if and only if the image of each loop in $H$ under $\psi$ is trivial, i.e. if and only if $H$ contains $N$.